# $U=\{X\in \Bbb C^{2\times 2}:AX=XA \}$, then $\dim (U)\ge 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A\in \Bbb C^{2\times 2}$ and $U=\{X\in \Bbb C^{2\times 2}:AX=XA \}$, then $\dim (U)\ge 2$

I know the statement can be generalized to $C^{n \times n}$, and I think I should split it into two cases, namely, $A$ is diagonalizable and $A$ is not diagonalizable. But I think I miss something and can not prove it. Appreciate any suggestion.

Here is what I have done: If $A$ is diagonalizable, then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=D$ is diagonal. If $XA=AX$, then I do not know how to use the fact $A$ is diagonalizable to get the desired result.

Comment: Note that the identity and $A$ itself always commute with $A$

Comment: @MikeDaas It looks like we are done?

Comment: Yep, just be sure to note that, should the identity and $A$ by linearly dependent, then of course every matrix will commute with $A$, so that the result still holds